# Problems intalling Elementary OS on a MacBook 4.1

Tags: system-installation, grub, macbook

I have a MacBook 4.1 (the black one) and I'm trying to use it again with elementary OS Loki.

I manage to make a USB Bootable, and now i'm trying to install the OS. I want to make Elementary my standalone system. OSX doesn't work that it use to, so I want to remove it.

When boot in Elementary, everithing worlks fine, I can test all the apps and I can install. The installation process is ok.

My problem is when the installation software try to install grub. It simply crash. The problem is that it is not able to install grub.

All the information I have consulted in the internet says that everuthing should work, so i don't understand.

Please can anyone help me?

I'm using the last Loki Build.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I manage to install Loki on my Macbook.

I redownload the iso, I reflash the USB on another USB with rufus, and finally it works.

Thanks for the support.